# How do I prove that a subset of a manifold is not a submanifold?

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

I know of ways to prove that a given subset of a smooth manifold is a smooth submanifold, but what if I have some subset which I suspect is not a smooth submanifold? What are some approaches to proving that it is not?

Comment: It depends on your definition of what a submanifold is...

Comment: What leads you to suspect otherwise? That might suggest something (or perhaps not). For example, maybe you suspect that there is a "corner"; then you could prove somewhere there can't be a smooth parametrization, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S\subset M$ is a subset of the manifold $M$, then it has a tangent cone $C(s)$ at every $s\in S$, which consists of the tangent vectors at $0$ of smooth  curves $\gamma:I\to S$, where $ I\subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval containing  $0 $ .
A necessary condition for $S$ to be a submanifold of dimension $k$  is that $C(s)$ be a vector space of dimension $k$ at every $s\in S$.

**An example**
If $M=\mathbb R^2$ and $S$ is the graph of the function  $|x|$, then at $O=(0,0)$ the cone $C(O)$ is the zero vector space  and at every other point of $s\in S$ the tangent cone $C(s)$ is $1$-dimensional.
Thus $S$ is not a submanifold of $M$.

Comment: The example also answers [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/462781/3217).

Comment: ...and tangent cones also yield  [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319396/3217)